Universal Monster Rules
In the d20pfsrd page for universal monster rules (https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/), the entries for Burrow, Constrict, Energy Drain, and Negative Energy Affinity have asterisks by their titles, but I can see no indication of what these refer to.  Archives of Nethys doesn't show anything special for these entries.  Any idea on what's special about these abilities?

To further the investigation with a possible clue, I submit that they might all be in need of a note like Burrow has ("Burrow details were not included in this game so the details shown here were copied from d20srd.org"), but this would require confirming with treeware versions of each ability.

There's some evidence that it may have been to mark abilities for which the d20 database differs from official material.
Burrow, as pointed out in the question's comments, lacks an official description entirely so the d20 version is borrowed from the D&D 3.5 database (specifically here, which appears to correspond more to the Special Ability appendix of the Core Rulebook than the UMR).
Negative Energy Affinity does not appear in the UMR for Bestiary 1, nor does any monster from Bestiary 1 have it. It appears in the UMR from Bestiary 2 onward (including my first printing paper B2). However, it is notable that there are multiple wordings of the ability in circulation, and that d20 does not match the paper sources, so it's reasonable to guess that a note on sourcing should be present.
This is the wording used by Archives of Nethys as well as my paper copies of B2,B3, and B5 (I don't own B4 or B6):

The creature is alive but reacts to positive and negative energy as if it were undead— positive energy harms it, negative energy heals it.

Meanwhile, this is the text used by d20 and, oddly, the older official database supplanted by Nethys:

The creature is alive but is healed by negative energy and harmed by positive energy, as if it were an undead creature.

The 3.5e page does also include entries for Energy Drain and Constrict, however these are both described in the Bestiary's UMR section (I have a third printing from 2011) exactly as they also appear in the current d20 Pathfinder UMR. As such, I'm not able to indicate why they might need a note.
